# Can one fly domestically in the US with only a work permit as ID?

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, paperwork

My girlfriend has a work permit. It doesn't expire for 4 more months. I told her to get an additional ID but she never did, so all she has is her work permit.

She's not a citizen of the US but she lives here. She pays about 500
dollars every few years to obtain a US government issued work permit which
allows her to be employed but I don't fully understand it so I don't
know if she can use that to fly.

I don't even know if she has a passport. She keeps saying she doesn't
have one. She's stranded in LA. She lives in Missouri. I'm trying to buy her a plane ticket to come back home. If she has a passport, she didn't bring
it. I asked her and she said well I have my work permit with me. No mention
of a passport.

Will she still be able to get on a plane and fly within the us?

She does *not* have a visa (as stated previously). She kept calling her work permit a visa. She has a work permit that doesn't expire until next year.

Comment: Please note that your question is now on hold. The single reason for that seems to be that you haven't clarified whether you're talking about a payment card or a travel document.

Comment: @JonathanReez OP has clarified now.

Comment: @Fiksdal still unclear to me. I suppose OP could be referring to a Green Card, which is indeed separate from a passport.

Comment: Maybe you can post a picture of what she claims she _does_ have, after blurring out any personal info. I think it would help you get better answers if we can stop second guessing what she does or does not have. You can ask her to scan the document(s) or use the webcam through Skype, for example.

Comment: Yes. OP: clarify what your girlfriend does have, and tell us. Until you do, there's now way to help you. @CompuChip

Comment: @JonathanReez I certainly agree that it's still unclear. We now know that it's not a VISA payment card, but we're still quite unsure what sort of document OP's girlfriend actually has.

Comment: @Fiksdal the US does issue visas on a separate piece of paper in some circumstances. The only such circumstance of which I am certain is that of the queen of the United Kingdom, who has no passport, but I imagine there must be others. IIRC travelers from unrecognized countries also get this treatment, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Bachtoven: how well do you know this woman? The story sounds rather reminiscent of a scam. I unaware of any US residence document that costs $500 every few years. Also, is impossible to get a visa inside the US unless you're a diplomat -- and diplomatic visas are free of charge.

Comment: @phoog Interesting. Thanks for letting me know. I think we can rule out the possibility that OPs girlfriend is the Queen of England, but the other options seem possible. In either case, OP needs to clarify :)

Comment: @Fiksdal anyway if the story is true she's not getting a visa but rather a new I-94 or the like. You can't get a visa while you're in the US, and it's not necessary to have a valid visa to stay in the US. It is possible she's using the term visa loosely, which could explain the lack of a passport, but it's also possible it's a scam.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, hard to tell until OP clarifies further.

Comment: Beethoven: the employment authorization document (EAD, work permit) costs $465. She could be talking about that. If so, it is acceptable ID for boarding a plane, according to the TSA.

Comment: Bachtoven: Sorry for calling you 'beethoven'; my phone made me do it.

Comment: It seems an EAD can be renewed by just using the old EAD too in most circumstances

Comment: @phoog She finally clarified it was a work permit. She kept calling it a visa so I don't know why but it's a work permit. Also, not a scam. We've been dating for 2.5 years. I just never bothered to know about how her citizenship works since she said visa so I assumed visa

Comment: @Bachtoven: Please edit the question to bring the information in it up to your current state of knowledge.

Comment: Is her work permit a I-766 employment authorization document (looks like [this](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/images/Verification/I9Central/NewestEADFront.JPG))? If so, the TSA will accept that as valid ID, as noted below.

Comment: @Bachtoven Yes, OP, please add as many details about the work permit (except for your girlfriends personal information) so that this question can be reopened.

Comment: @phoog Beethoven and the Queen of England... LOL :)

Comment: @Fiksdal: I recall another question recently for which, in order to give a definitive answer, we should have asked the OP a clarifying question: "Are you the Pope?"

Comment: "She pays about 500 dollars every few years to obtain a US government issued work permit which allows her to be employed" - what?

Comment: @hyankov see https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/information-for-employers-and-employees/employer-information/employment-authorization

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Now that we've cleared up the fact that the document is a work permit, I'll assume it's an I-766 Employment Authorization Document ([image searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=i+766) indicate that the card itself says "Employment Authorization Card," and that the indication "Form I-766" is found on the back of the card).

According to the TSA, this document can be used to board a flight.  The list is at https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification, and the last entry, as of this writing, is

> Immigration and Naturalization Service Employment Authorization Card (I-766)

Answer (score 9):

[This page](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) lists the forms of ID that are accepted by the US Transportation Security Administration for a domestic flight. A visa is not on the list. However:

> Foreign government-issued passport

Is acceptable. Assuming she has a valid passport (presumably the one containing the visa), she can use that as ID.

Also note that a "Immigration and Naturalization Service Employment Authorization Card (I-766)" is an acceptable form of ID, if this is the document she possesses. It is hard to tell exactly what kind of "visa" she has (assuming she has not been taken by a scam). If you can update your question with a picture of it (with her personal information blacked out), we should be able to help you better.

Comment: She may be using "visa" to refer to an employment authorisation document, which doesn't require a passport ("visa which allows her to be employed"). Or maybe it's a scam.

Comment: Of course, is the "visa" really is an EAD, she can use it to fly.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote, but it may be because the answer no longer reflects the clarified question.

Answer (score 1):

I have that same permit also. Obama made it possible for us who came at a young age illegally to be able to stay in this country legally to work and get a driver's lisence . Only thing is, it expires every two years and have to get it renwed for $475 , prices went up. Yes she can board the plane with it, I have before.

Comment: You can also use your foreign passport, if you have one.